# How should the canned comments in the low-quality queue be used?

Tags: support, faq, comments, review

When I review answers in the low-quality queue and choose *Delete* or *Recommend Deletion,* respectively, I can choose from a series of comments or *No comment needed.*
What effect do they have and when should I choose such a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The canned comments are really just what you see; there is no hidden function. Use them only when they really apply and provide useful guidance.

## What does it do?

If you choose a comment from that queue, it will be left as a regular comment on the answer with you as the author.
The system will add a link *From Review* leading to the respective review item.
If somebody chose this canned comment before you, their comment will be upvoted on your behalf instead.

**And that is it.**
Your review or the post won’t be treated any differently because you chose a certain comment or no comment.
In particular choosing *This is commentary on another post* does not initiate any systematic steps towards the answer being converted to a comment.
There is no statistics (available to users or moderators) how often you or anybody else chose a certain comment.

So these comments only have two effects:

- They provide guidance to the author as to what is wrong with their post, how they can fix it, or what they can do instead of answering.
- They tell other reviewers and visitors what you think is wrong with the post.

## How should I use them?

- If you or somebody else already left a comment explaining what is wrong with the answer, upvote that comment and choose *No comment needed.* (If the existing comment is a canned comment from the queue, choosing the same comment again would have the same effect, however, the first variant is safer since sometimes what looks like a canned comment from the queue was posted manually or by a userscript.)
- If one of the canned comments applies perfectly to the post, choose this.
- If one of the canned comments applies, but there is more to say, choose the comment, go to the post, and either edit it or leave another comment.

  A typical case would be if somebody posts a question as an answer that would be closed in its current state:
  By telling the user directly what they need to improve before posting it as a question, you avoid a tedious and disappointing back-and-forth later.
- Most importantly, if none of the comments apply, choose *No comment needed.*
  Preferably leave a regular comment to explain what you think is wrong with the post.
  However, if you do not want to do this for some reason, **it is better to leave no guidance than bad guidance**.

  In particular, do not use *This is commentary on another post, not an answer*¹ unless the post really would be a valid comment, i.e., a request for clarification, criticism on a post, a relevant link, a really good joke, or similar.
  Answers to another question, rants, or similar are not valid comments.
  Also, a long post (say, more than 600 characters) is very unlikely to be a valid comment.
  Leaving said canned comment on such posts is confusing for the author and does not help them to understand what is wrong.

---

¹ Which is (for users below 50 reputation):

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).